# MatInput label overlay doesn't move out of the input box in angular form

Tags: angular, angular-material

On some of my form fields the field label doesn't move up to top border of field when you start typing in the input box.  It just sits there in the middle of the box, and the character you type overlay the label, as in example below.  I saw some suggestion about reloading built in themes but no help there.

[image]

```
<form [formGroup]="bindingAuthorForm" (submit)="submit()">
      <div class="input-area">
        <div class="left-right-area">
          <div id="left-col">
            <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Binding Name</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="bindingName" required #binding_name>
              <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['bindingName'].hasError('pattern')">
                <span *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['bindingName'].errors['required']">This field is
                  mandatory.</span>
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error>
                <span *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['bindingName'].errors['pattern']">Lowercase letters, numbers and
                  underscore only.
                </span>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Version</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="version" required #version_number autocomplete="nope" >
              <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['version'].hasError('pattern')">
                <span>Version must be Major.Minor.Patch style, e.g. '1.2.3'</span>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Author</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="authorName" required autocomplete="nope" >
              <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['authorName'].hasError('required')">
                <span>Author Name is required. </span>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Short Description</mat-label>
              <textarea matInput placeHolder="Description" formControlName="plainText"></textarea>
              <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['plainText'].hasError('maxlength')">
                <span>The short description is limited to 140 characters. </span>
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['plainText'].hasError('badTags')">
                <span>HTML tags, and '&'s aren't permitted here </span>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div id="right-col">
            <div id="template-text">
              <app-template-text #template_text></app-template-text>
              <div class="template-text-footer">
                <mat-error *ngIf="template_text.isError && template_text.touched">{{template_text.errorString}}
                </mat-error>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <a class="hover-toggle" mat-stroked-button (click)="showAttributes()">Attributes <mat-icon>help
                  </mat-icon>
                </a>
                <a class="hover-toggle" mat-stroked-button>Bindings <mat-icon>help</mat-icon></a>                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 
        <!-- <div class="footer-area">-->
        <div class=template-errors><p>{{errorMessages}}</p></div>
        <!-- <span [ngClass]="bindingAuthorForm.controls.bindingType.hasError('required') ? 'mark-error' : ''"> Binding Type
          * </span> -->
        <mat-button-toggle-group class="toggle-group" formControlName="bindingType" #binding_type
          [(value)]="bindingTypestring">

          <mat-button-toggle value="Definitions">Definitions</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Entitlements">Entitlements</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Restrictions">Restrictions</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Reps">Publisher Reps</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Section">Section Header</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Schedule">Schedule</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Template">Template</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="Other">Other</mat-button-toggle>
        </mat-button-toggle-group>
        <div class="action_buttons">
          <button class="submit-button" [disabled]="formInvalid" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Post to
            Blockchain</button>
          <button class="cancel-button" mat-raised-button color="alert">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with floatLabel="auto" to force label to float on top while typing a value in input as below -

```
<mat-form-field class="form-field" appearance="outline" floatLabel="auto">
                  <mat-label>Version</mat-label>
                  <input matInput formControlName="version" required #version_number autocomplete="nope" >
                  <mat-error *ngIf="bindingAuthorForm.controls['version'].hasError('pattern')">
                    <span>Version must be Major.Minor.Patch style, e.g. '1.2.3'</span>
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the height works for me:

```
input {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, old thread, but I updated from Angular/Material 13 to 15 and this started happening on every element. It was most frustrating, so I hope this comment helps someone else.

This thread held the solution: [Problems after Angular Material update from 14 to 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75311923/problems-after-angular-material-update-from-14-to-15)

I had to run this bit of code. After I did that, restarted VS code, and re-ran my application, all the outlines worked perfectly. Some of the styles needed tweaking, but they would actually cooperate.

```
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```