# Problems after Angular Material update from 14 to 15

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14, angular15, angular-migration

I'm working on an Angular project, updated from angular14 to 15, but after I install the new Material package the whole project seems visually broken. Wrong colors, margins, paddings.
The project only contains css style files, not scss. I think the problem will be with the legacy material components, but how/where should I add to the project?
Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I think I figured out, just have to put that line in the style.css: ../node_modules/@angular/material/legacy-prebuilt-themes/*find your not legacy package*

Comment: In my case I just ran this command. 
`ng add @angular/material`
Then choose prebuilt theme from the list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change css file to legacy in `styles`(angular.json)

F.e

from
`"./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",`

to
`"./node_modules/@angular/material/legacy-prebuilt-themes/legacy-pink-bluegrey.css",`

Comment: I have different CSS what should do ?  "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css".

After Change "~@angular/material/legacy-prebuilt-themes/legacy-indigo-pink.css". So it will five error

Comment: @tczkqq i am also getting error after import legacy css

Comment: this just blew up my app completely. Where did you find this documentation?

Comment: In my case I just ran this command. 
ng add @angular/material
Then choose prebuilt theme from the list.

Answer (score 10):

As it is detailed in the [official documentation](https://rc.material.angular.io/guide/mdc-migration#1-update-to-angular-material-v15), you need to update the material version with this command.

```bash
ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
```

Note that this update will potentially break the logic of your application, as it introduce breaking changes.

But it will provide your application with all the new angular styles.

I assume that you have already run `ng update @angular/material@15`

Answer (score 5):

The solution for me was to include the legacy theme and core provided by material theming.

Additionally to core include legacy-core:

```
@include mat.core();
@include mat.legacy-core();
```

and additionally to all-component-themes include all-legacy-component-themes:

```
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
@include mat.all-legacy-component-themes($theme);
```

I updated with nx migrate and nx did not automatically migrate, but refactored all Material Components to Legacy. This messed up all styling completely without the themes and core included correctly.

Comment: Hi @lajuma how did you resolve the TODO(mdc-migration): comments left by MDC? Where can we refer which material class needs to be replaced with which equivalent class in MDC? I am really stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just ran this command.
`ng add @angular/material`
Then choose prebuilt theme from the list.